# Firebase/React: Get Document ID before creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wanting to assign the ID on a firebase add before submit.

```
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('trips').doc();
const tripid = ref.id;
```

This works well, but I notice everytime I change or edit a field prior to submitting that this tripid variable changes. Basically I have an upload function that stores the document under their User ID / tripid.

If assigning the const of ref.id - how do I avoid this changing on field edits? As if they upload a document it goes into the ID at that time, and then if they edit other fields before submit the ID changes, and the reference is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your component function looks something like this:

```
function YourComponent({ props }) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");  
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");

  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('trips').doc();
  const tripid = ref.id;

  return ( /* ... form ... */ );
}
```

Every time that component rerenders, the generated ref will change.

To prevent this, you need to introduce a function that generates your reference just once and leaves it untouched when you redraw your component. This can be done using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

```
function YourComponent({ props }) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");  
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  
  // create `ref` once on the first render, don't recompute it even on redraws
  const ref = useMemo(
    () => firebase.firestore().collection('trips').doc(),
    [] // no dependencies, don't recompute
  );

  const tripid = ref.id;

  return ( /* ... form ... */ );
}
```

However in the future `useMemo` won't be able to be used this way (and it warns as such in [its documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), so we can create our own like so:

```
// fork of useMemo, this can be elsewhere in your code so you can reuse it
function usePersistentObject(init, deps) {
  const obj = useRef(null);
  const prevDeps = useRef(deps || []);

  if (obj.current === null || !(prevDeps.current.length === deps.length && prevDeps.current.every((v, i) => deps[i] === v))) { // rough shallow equals, could use a library
    // either first render or deps array values changed
    obj.current = init();    // compute
    prevDeps.current = deps; // save dependency state
  }

  return obj.current;
}

function YourComponent({ props }) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");  
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  
  // create `ref` once on the first render, don't recompute it even on redraws
  const ref = usePersistentObject(
    () => firebase.firestore().collection('trips').doc(),
    [] // no dependencies, don't recompute
  );

  const tripid = ref.id;

  return ( /* ... form ... */ );
}
```

**Note:** If `YourComponent` is unmounted the reference will change!

Comment: Thanks for that. If I try console.log on tripid - I get an undefined error?

Comment: @PaulVI Sorry, I still get my hooks mixed up all the time. Updated.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman - I implemented this solution and it does not seem like the ID changes when re-rendering - however when I submit the form the ID is different

Comment: just revisiting this, and I noticed that after submitting the ID stays the same - how do I generate a new ID once they submit the form? Or how do I refresh the ID

Comment: @PaulVI You could add a "lastSubmittedTime" variable somewhere (or something else that will change once submitted), pass it into `YourComponent` as a property then add it inside the dependencies of the `useMemo`/`usePersistentObject` call (i.e. `[]` to `[props.lastSubmittedTime]`). As long as the variable doesn't change, a new ID won't be computed for the life of the component.